# How to approximate linear relationship between two timeseries?

Tags: transformation, matlab, linear-regression

I have two time series A and B

I would like to solve for the equation in the form $$y_t = m x_t + b$$  that transforms a point $y$ at time $t$ from series $B$ to the corresponding point $x$ at time $t$ from $A$.

How do I approximate $m$ and $b$ given $A$ and $B$?

Is there an easy way to do this in MATLAB or Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).

In Excel, if $A$ data is in `A1:A7` and $B$ data is in `B1:B7`, select two cells and in the formula enter `=LINEST(B1:B7, A1:A7,TRUE,FALSE)` and press Ctrl-Shift-Enter. The first number will be $m$, the second -- $b$.

Look up [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html?refresh=true) for MATLAB

Comment: Could the one who downvoted please explain the downvote? The OP explicitly asked for a Excel/Matlab solution...

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.